# Fetch local date and time using lat-long

Tags: php, datetime, geolocation, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I've found tons of resources that are able to give the local offset from UTC using the lat long I supply. However I'm confused because of the different time zones and day light savings. I am looking for a straightforward approach or API where I just plug in my lat and long (because that's all I have in my application) and I get the local time and local date.

Thanks in advance

P.S. - I'm working in PHP and hence need php related solutions :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates

Comment: https://derickrethans.nl/what-time-is-it.html

Comment: If you need help about the concept of time zone you should be more specific about it, and possibly include some code. Otherwise, library/service recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Geonames should do the job nicely:

http://www.geonames.org/

They've also got a php library.

For more detail of how this works please check [HERE](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-calculate-time-using-longitudes-and-latitudes)